# AS3: Drag to select multiple tiles in TileList

Tags: actionscript-3, tilelist

Im working a project with two of my fellow students and we would like to be able to drag the cursor over a tilelist to select multiple tiles. We cant really find any function to do this, is it possible to do it some how?

Best regards

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea of what you want to accomplish:

```
tileList = new TileList();
tileList.allowMultipleSelection = true;
tileList.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startSelecting);
tileList.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopSelecting);

function startSelecting(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    tileList.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    if (CellRenderer(e.target))
    {
        CellRenderer(e.target).selected = true;
    }
}

function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if (CellRenderer(e.target))
    {
        CellRenderer(e.target).selected = true;
    }
}

function stopSelecting(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    tileList.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
}
```

You'll definitely want to customize this to suit your needs, but basically it adds a few mouse event listeners to the tile list and selects any tile that has been rolled over while the mouse button is pressed.

Comment: Perfecto, just what I need.